# Can a Flutter app be proposed on the Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: android, flutter, apk, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Some Huawei mobile devices don't have the Google Play Store and have the Huawei AppGallery instead. Since Flutter is for cross-platform development (iOS and Android), it may be desirable to propose Flutter developed apps through the Huawei AppGallery.

The Huawei devices without the Google Play Store are still using Android and the applications to upload to the Huawei AppGallery must have the `apk` extension (just like in the Google Play Store). These are hunches that at least some Google Play Store applications can be proposed on the Huawei AppGallery. However, I did not find any proof or confirmation of this. Nor any clear perimeter for this compatibility. For example, some services may not work or may not be accepted on the Huawei AppGallery for technical or legal reasons. One part of this perimeter is the use of Flutter to develop the application.

So, my question is, **can a Flutter developed application be compatible with the Huawei AppGallery** and if so, under which conditions?

**Edit after first app publication 2020 04 13**

My first Flutter app has just been published on the Huawei AppGallery. This answers the first part of the question.
Still, as this app is quite minimalist, this doesn't answer the most important part which is: under which conditions can a Flutter app be published on the Huawei AppGallery?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as your application complies with the regulations of AppGallery, there should not be any problem it.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30202

AppGallery does not have any restriction on the language application developed with, no need to worry about it; flutter, cordova, react.native, xamarin they are fine.

Just a point to take care. If you are using SDKs or services those depend on Google Play services, when you have published your application on AppGallery, it will be visible only for Huawei devices supports Google Play Services.

Answer (score 11):

There are no restrictions on the Flutter apps. They can be released on HUAWEI AppGallery.

**How to release an app:**

1. Register and sign in to your HUAWEI Developer account, go to AppGallery Connect, create a new app, and upload the APK.
2. Set languages and basic app information, such as app name, introduction, screenshots, and app category.
3. Select your business model (free or premium), release countries and regions, and a link to the privacy statement.
4. Confirm that all of the information provided is correct, and submit your app for review.

As @captaink said, please also refer to [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30202?ha_source=hms1).

---

If your app has integrated GMS Kit, these capabilities provided via GMS are not available on Huawei phones with HMS. If you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/?ha_source=hms1).

Huawei has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for Flutter. They have been published to public open source communities. You can also find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin).

[Account Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050766441?ha_source=hms1)

[Ads Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/publisher-service-0000001050196431?ha_source=hms1)

[Analytics Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050169136?ha_source=hms1)

[AR Kit plugin for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001058897997-V1?ha_source=hms1)

[In-App Purchases Kit plugin for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001051001685?ha_source=hms1)

[Location Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050191280?ha_source=hms1)

[Map Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050296908?ha_source=hms1)

[Push Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050176002?ha_source=hms1)

[Scan Kit plugin for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001054309573-V1?ha_source=hms1)

[Site Kit plugins for Flutter](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050181259?ha_source=hms1)

Comment: How about push notifications? In Android they are supported through Firebase (which I assume has some tie-in with Google Play Services). Does this methodology also work on Huawei devices?

Comment: For the Huawei devices having Play Services, FCM will work fine. Meanwhile, new Huawei devices (starting by Mate 30 series) do not have Play Services. Hence, you need to use Huawei Push Kit in your application. Alternative is using a push services provider which supports both FCM and Huawei Push Kit, e.g. Airship, dEngage, Netmera...

Comment: @cheeze For [Flutter Push Plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050176002)

Answer (score 6):

In theory, yes it could. Huawei uses an OS called Harmony OS.

> The Arc compiler in Harmony OS supports all the major programming languages including C/, C++, Java, JavaScript and Kotlin.

Flutter compiles Dart code to native device code (Java, and Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS). Huawei is making an Arc compiler that supposedly makes it easy to turn Android apps to Harmony OS apps. What does this mean for Flutter and the AppGallery? I'm not sure.

So to your question, in theory, yes it could but I would just recommend coding your own app in one of the languages mentioned above and using the Arc compiler to put it on Huawei's AppGallery.

**UPDATE:**

So apparently you can just put an APK on the Huawei App Gallery: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30204. Since you can obviously make APKs in Flutter, I don't see why not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Benjamin . Just like you, I believe it should be possible to propose a Flutter created apk to the Huawei AppGallery. For the reasons why not, I can only think of technical and legal constraints. Since Huawei is trying to get rid of services involving Google like the Play Store, are the proposed apks allowed to make use of Google services such as Firebase for example? Also, as Huawei are proposing their own services, they may or may not accept apks using equivalent Google services: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/help/100104

Comment: AFAIK, Huawei does not use Harmony OS yet. All the mobile phones are using Android.

Answer (score 2):

Update on this subject:
we received the communication from Huawei technical staff to **delete all Google Play Services in the app and substitute them with theirs Huawei Mobile Services, before the end of November 2020**.
It seems that after this date they don't accept Google Play Services inside the apps. Don't know if app published before will still be there after.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I found more on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63336006/2590508