# How To Start Developing Mobile Apps For Huawei

Tags: android, mobile, huawei-developers

I'd like to develop a mobile app for Huawei. Not much on the web about this subject. Do I just create an Android app or is there more to it for Huawei to accept a mobile app in their store?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration from Google Play Store to Huawei Store. Any changes in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872524/migration-from-google-play-store-to-huawei-store-any-changes-in-code)

Comment: Please don't edit your question into an an entirely different question.  Someone has already taken the time to write an answer to your question, and changing the question makes their answer make no sense.  Simply ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Any of your Android app can be released to Huawei AppGallery as long as it comply with the [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202?ha_source=hms1).

---

**How to release an app:**

1. Register and sign in to your HUAWEI Developer account, go to AppGallery Connect, create a new app, and upload the APK.
2. Set languages and basic app information, such as app name, introduction, screenshots, and app category.
3. Select your business model (free or premium), release countries and regions, and a link to the privacy statement.
4. Confirm that all of the information provided is correct, and submit your app for review.

---

You can also use [Huawei Mobile Services(HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms?ha_source=hms1), which provides a variety of service capabilities to app developers from App Services, Graphics, Media, AI, Smart Device, Security and System. For example, with Account Kit, users can one-click sign in to your app. The integration is quick and easy.