# App installed via Huawei app gallery clearing data from background when moved to background

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, kill-process

Recently we had an incident which I felt worthy of sharing here to get your feedback.

One of our customer had a strange issue, wherein the app installed on devices having only Huawei App Gallery gets its background data cleared when the app is just moved to background. Did anyone face such an issue ? What might have gone wrong? Please share your thoughts on this.

*Note: This app was rolled out in Play Store, App Store, and Apple Store. Only users who used Huawei phones that don't  have Google Play Store faced this issue. Huawei devices with both Play Store and App Gallery worked fine as well.*

Comment: 1. Please can you provide the android logs for application starting from the application launch,going into background and coming foreground.

2. What type of data is lost?. Please can you share the screenshot/video of the issue, showing the data lose.

Comment: Thanks Kiruba. We finally got the issue. It was because firebase sdk not support in Huawei.

Comment: @SajidK.P, which firebase SDK do you use? Huawei also provides corresponding capabilities, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63461164/13329100).